# F# : file parsing

Tags: f#

This is my first post on this site :-) I'm learning F#. To do this, I try to resolve the Euler problems (http://projecteuler.net/). In the 11th problem (http://projecteuler.net/problem=11), the first task to accomplish is to parse a file which contains this 20x20 grid :

```
08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48
```

I wrote this code to parse the file, and I tried to do it in a "functional" way. It works but I find it a little bit complex compared to what I could write in C# :

```
open System
open System.IO

let readLines =
    seq {
        use sr = new StreamReader("Input.txt")
        while not sr.EndOfStream do
            yield sr.ReadLine()
    } |> Seq.zip (Seq.ofList [0..19])

let parseLine tupleLine =
    let (index:int, line:string) = tupleLine
    line.Split( [| ' ' |] )
    |> Array.map(fun s -> Int32.Parse(s))
    |> Seq.zip [| 0 .. 19 |]
    |> Seq.map (fun tl -> (index, fst tl, snd tl))

let tabNumbers = Array.create 400 0

let fillArray tupleNumber =
    let (line, column, number) = tupleNumber
    tabNumbers.[20 * line + column] <- number

readLines
|> Seq.map parseLine
|> ignore
```

Is there a simplier way to accomplish this ?
Thank you in advance !

PS : Excuse me for my bad english...

Comment: Perhaps you should not do it line-based, but split on every whitespace character instead.

Comment: Your English isn't bad. (La seule 'faute' c'est de mettre des espaces avant les `:?!`) PS. as-tu vu http://french.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a corresponding version of your code:

```
let readLines =
  "Input.txt"
  |> File.ReadAllLines
  |> Array.mapi (fun i line -> (i, line)) 

let parseLine (i, line) =
  line.Split([|' '|])
  |> Array.mapi (fun j s -> i, j, Int32.Parse(s))
```

Or you can combine them to have a more succinct version:

```
let readAll =
  "Input.txt"
  |> File.ReadAllLines
  |> Array.mapi (fun i line -> line.Split([|' '|])
                               |> Array.mapi (fun j s -> i, j, Int32.Parse(s)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and for the Array.mapi function ! Your solution is more clean and clear than mine !

Edit : I trid to say that your answer is useful, but I've not enoiugh reputation to do that...